# Neovim coc-html don't use auto-closing tag for macros?

Tags: neovim, plugin-coc

I am using neovim and coc.vim for lsp.
Also for html used coc-html.
But i have an bug, when write or use macros, have 2 closing tags.
How can i disable this behaviour?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be good if you could give an example of start text, input keys, end text and expected end text such that we can reproduce the problem. Maybe should we also check that there are no collusion with [emmet-vim](https://github.com/mattn/emmet-vim) or Ultisnip or other templating engine if you use some.

Comment: Thanks for unswer. 
The problem is in plugin coc-html, because if i uninstall it with `:CocUninstall coc-html` and write or run macros, than don't appear closing tag.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
Disable coc-html and use this plugin for closing tag https://github.com/alvan/vim-closetag

And don't need to auto close tag, just run :CloseTagToggleBuffer